# Google Apps Script: How can use js library in HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make carousel in google site using Google Apps Script. This carousel includes text messages that would be changed dynamically. I am using jquery to implement this but GAS HtmlService api is not able to evalute that js script files.

I used http://flexslider.com carousel in my application. But its not working.
I also tried with caja playground but it does not have carousel implementation js file.
I upload all required js files to google cloud storage and made them public.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/shCore.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/shBrushXml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/shBrushJScript.js"></script>

 <!-- Optional FlexSlider Additions -->
<script src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script defer src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/demo.js"></script>
```

Any suggestion to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of Caja which sanitizes the script and filters some of the code from your js.
Check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#Caja) for details.

Alternatively, you can use Google Drive Webhost to publish your carousel and then embed it in Google Site using publicly available iFrame gadget.
Check a similar demo here
https://sites.google.com/site/appsdatepicker/test-page-2

Comment: Thanks Waqar for your quick reply. I also worked with this approach. For this i have created a google presentation with required effects and then published it on web then added to my google site as a gadget. It was working well. But i want to update content of presentation dynamically . Means each slide would be get text from the google apps script dynamically. Have you any solution to change or upload google presentation's content??

Comment: Hello Ruchi Ji, I am not sure if you understood me correctly. I am not talking about any Google presentation. It is a simple JS and html files uploaded in Google Drive in a public folder which is then accessesd through weblink link like (https://googledrive.com/host/PUBLIC_FOLDER_ID_HERE), which is then embedded in Google Site using iFrame Gadget. These links may help you. http://goo.gl/5XR6u

Comment: Thank you Waqar Ji, now i understood your answer perfectly. I didn't know about the google webhosting, but now i got it. Thanks a tonne.

Comment: @Frederic I'll recommend you to ask this question in  Google Drive Product forum (http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/drive)